# Resolve " fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory " in Visual Studio Code with mingW g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I get the error ***"fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory"*** when i try to compile this simple code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main()
{

}
```

I'm using ***Visual Studio Code 2019*** with ***mingW g++ 8.1.0***, the IDE is able to locate ***"GLFW/glfw3.h"*** he can even open it when doing a right click 'Go to Definition' but the compilator can't, how to resolve this error ?

EDIT: There are the JSON files used to compile the code:

launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Mingw\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

c_cpp_propreties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/VulkanSDK/1.2.154.1/Include/**",
            "/Projects/Libraries/glm/**",
            "/Projects/Libraries/glfw-3.3.2/include/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\Mingw\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-o",
            "main",
            "-g",
            "main.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {"kind": "build", "isDefault": true}
    }
]
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: you've added `launch.json` twice, your compiler commands are presumably in `tasks.json`

Comment: You need to specify your includes in `tasks.json`, `c_cpp_propreties.json` only controls intellisense

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @TheMexican There don't seem to be any settings in tasks.json to help the compiler locate header files. includePath in c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense only (which as you say is working)

Comment: @John Thanks, i resolved the error by adding the HeaderFilePaths with "-IC:/HFPaths" command in the tasks.json like you said.